# popBackStack() is not working in android NavController

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I am using android JetPack navigation to navigate between my fragments. This is how my `navigation graph` looks like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/registration_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/registrationStoreNameFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationStoreNameFragment"
    android:name="com.minidukaan.android.feature.registration.view.RegistrationStoreNameFragment"
    android:label="fragment_registration_store_name"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_registration_store_name" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_registrationStoreNameFragment_to_registrationStoreUrlFragment2"
        app:destination="@id/registrationStoreUrlFragment2" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationStoreUrlFragment2"
    android:name="com.minidukaan.android.feature.registration.view.RegistrationStoreUrlFragment"
    android:label="RegistrationStoreUrlFragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_registrationStoreUrlFragment2_to_registrationLocationFragment"
        app:destination="@id/registrationLocationFragment" />
    <argument
        android:name="store_name"
        app:argType="string" />
    <argument
        android:name="store_slug"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationLocationFragment"
    android:name="com.minidukaan.android.feature.registration.view.RegistrationLocationFragment"
    android:label="fragment_registration_location"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_registration_location" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_registrationLocationFragment_to_registrationSuccessFragment"
        app:destination="@id/registrationSuccessFragment" />
    <argument
        android:name="store_name"
        app:argType="string" />
    <argument
        android:name="store_slug"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue=""/>
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationSuccessFragment"
    android:name="com.minidukaan.android.feature.registration.view.RegistrationSuccessFragment"
    android:label="fragment_registration_success"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_registration_success" />
```

From `RegistrationStoreNameFragment` I navigate to `RegistrationStoreUrlFragment` like this

```
private lateinit var navController: NavController
override fun init(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.init(savedInstanceState)
    ....

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    navController = view?.let { Navigation.findNavController(it) }!!
    val action = RegistrationStoreNameFragmentDirections.
                        actionRegistrationStoreNameFragmentToRegistrationStoreUrlFragment2(storeName, it.slug)
                            navController.navigate(action)
```

}

so it navigates perfectly, but when I do `navController.popBackStack()` in `RegistrationStoreUrlFragment` then it doesn't navigate back. Any help will be highly appreciated as I am stuck in this issue for a long time.

For other fragments popBackStack is working fine but not for the ones mentioned above.

Comment: `findNavController().navigate(R.id. action_registrationLocationFragment_to_registrationSuccessFragment)`

Comment: So `init()` is unconditionally navigating? Are you sure `popBackStack()` isn't working perfectly, but you instantly navigate a second time right back to the destination you just popped?

Comment: @ianhanniballake it is just for the question sake that i put it in `init()` otherwise i am navigating on button click

Comment: @ianhanniballake thanks. It was acting happening same thing as you mentioned but instead of init it was in observer of liveData. So it was happening so fast that seemed like popBackStack wasnt working. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When do you want to navigate?

If on any custom event you want to navigate back to a previously added fragment then,

You have to define **popUpTo** action under your **Fragment** tag in **NavGraph**,

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/registrationStoreUrlFragment2"
android:name="com.minidukaan.android.feature.registration.view.RegistrationStoreUrlFragment"
android:label="RegistrationStoreUrlFragment" >
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_pop_back"
        app:destination="@id/registrationSuccessFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/registrationSuccessFragment"/>
</fragment>
```

And call it in the navigate like this,

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_pop_back)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Current fragment to back homeFragment**

```
 findNavController().popBackStack(R.id.homeFragment, true)
```

it's work fine for me. Maybe it will help you

Comment: I tried this but once you go back the currentDestination is null so you can't navigate forward again. What worked for me is adding the popUpTo destination in the nav graph.

Comment: findNavController().popUpTo(R.id.homeFragment, true)

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I had the same problem, I tried the solution given here by setting `app:popUpTo` in the `xml` but the problem for me was that the back Button only worked once in this case.
So then I set it like below with `app:popUpToSaveState`, now it works fine going back and forth:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/anonymous_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/startupFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/landingFragment"
        android:name="com.myApp.ui.landing.LandingFragment"
        android:label="fragment_landing"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_landing" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_landingFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToSaveState="@id/landingFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Then inside the code, I will call `navigateUp` when back pressed:

```
findNavController().navigateUp()
```